# Grid in the tab control is not getting refreshed with values after using updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

i am  using updatepanel under tab which contains grid.please find below the code structure

i have to refresh the grid with new values using ajax updatepanel by selecting the element in combobox control.My combo box does not support server side event . i am writing javascript function in my client side file which calls button event  in C# and  button is in updatepanel which is invisible

.

am using updatepanel.update() method in C# however the values are not being refreshed.

please provide solution for the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide a code sample that illustrates your issue (or a small non-working version)? At the moment it would be very hard for anyone to answer this question.

Comment: Can I have some code please?